# FTP for azure subfolders

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, filezilla

I have one azure account and I have 5 sub folders in it each having different website. I can access the root folder(and all sub folders) through FTP. Now I want to separate access to these 5 websites (with five different FTPs). Let me know how to do this..

Answer (score 2):

Azure doesn't allow such detailed permission configuration (per folder).

As far as I know the credentials you set for FTP are for the entire Azure subscription, not individual websites or folders.

Answer (score 0):

Each Web App accepts two kind of FTP credentials:

1. User credentials: always the same for a given user
2. Site credentials: each site has its own. You can get those by downloading the publishing profile for each site.

Sounds like you want #2.